# css print font not changing

Tags: html, css

Im designing a printer friendly page and im stuck trying to alter the font properties[font-size, font-family] in CSS.I have got no idea what im doing wrong here. The font properties i have specified for the body tag in the CSS file doesn't seem to work at all.

Could somone please explain to me what im doing wrong here ?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr >
            <td >Job No</td>
            <td>4589</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Job No</td>
            <td>6578</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
/* CSS Document */
div#wrapper 
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:auto;

}
body {
background-color: transparent;
font-size: 12pt;
font-family:'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
color:#000000; }
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Are you sure your CSS is linked correctly? All I did to test was create the files as above and change the font-family to Arial to see if it changed for the print version, and it worked.

Comment: really,this is so frustrating!! i have seen this work before but cant get it work now...im sorry mate but wud u be kind enuf to post me the code,just want to see if u hav done anything different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the font properties for the `td`:

```
table tr td {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family:'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but no joy,doesnt make any sense. even if i put 120 pt for font-size it wont have it.

Comment: @manraj strange. Are you sure the style sheet gets included? Can you try `table { display: none }` to see whether it has any effect at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS instead.

```
#wrapper
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:auto;
}

#wrapper table
{
  font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

body 
{
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color:#000000; 
}
```